# Google Map is loading on page load, just showing the Map box but doesn't show any thing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, google-maps

I am trying to implement the Google Map on basis of Lat. and Long. i have written following code for this.

```
<script>
function geoFindMe() {
    function success(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;



        var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&sensor=false';

        $.ajax({
            url: url, dataType: "json", async: false, success: function (result) {
                if (result.results) {
                    $('[id$=txLocation]').val(result.results[0].address_components[7].long_name);
                }
            }
        });
        initMap(latitude, longitude);

    }

    function error() {
        var latLong;
        $.getJSON("https://ipinfo.io", function (ipinfo) {
            console.log("Found location [" + ipinfo.loc + "] by ipinfo.io");
            latLong = ipinfo.loc.split(",");


            var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latLong[0] + ',' + latLong[1] + '&sensor=false';

            //  var URL1 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&key=AIzaSyAcFUUXsJBxElbLTx4cNFTGFIsmwf5PlSo'
            $.ajax({
                url: url, dataType: "json", async: false, success: function (result) {
                    if (result.results) {
                        $('[id$=txLocation]').val(result.results[0].address_components[7].long_name);
                    }
                }
            });
            initMap(latLong[0], latLong[1]);
        });

    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
function initMap(Lat, lang) {
    var myLatlng = { lat: Lat, lng: lang };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatlng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Click to zoom'
    });

    map.addListener('center_changed', function () {
        // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
        // marker.
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
        }, 3000);
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function () {
        map.setZoom(8);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });
}
```

It is loading like the following screenshot:

[image: Map]

When i press F12 it got works and shows the actual map.

Please help me. and tell what i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your console for messages...

Comment: @lonut no error in console..

Comment: Please post the whole code you have in a working snippet or create a https://jsfiddle.net. Now I don't even see when or how you call the `geoFindMe` function.

Comment: I posted all code.. that's it..just want to add script reference 

<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDMGgG0GsbiLmr6sutrKR5ImARnr55qyE8&callback=geoFindMe">
</script>

Comment: if you check the Script reference i posted in above comment then you can get that method is being used as callback function

Comment: That it's not true, where is the `HTML` code? You tagged this question as `HTML` but I don't see any. And regarding the script I don't see any api key parameter...you should set that. Also, if you say you don't get any errors, if you use Firebug please stop, it is not maintained anymore and its behaviour is unexpected, use the default browser inspect element to check for errors.

Comment: It is not recommended that you invoke the geocoding web service via AJAX on the client side like you are doing. You should invoke the service through the JS API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

I suspect that your problem, though, might be due to the fact that you are somehow inadvertently loading the JS API twice.